Does input have any from a list?
I have a list and want to know if my column contains any of the lists values.
Hello, I have a table with column colors which has one or many colors as inputs:
Example:
Column : Colors
Row 1  : RED
Row 2  : RED and GREEN
Row 3  : RED and ORANGE
Row 4  : ORANGE
Row 5  : GREEN AND MAGENTA
Row 6  : ORANGE AND BLACK

.....
My colleague gave me a list of 25 unique colors and wants to know if any of these colors are in my table.
I did this:
select 
        colors
        , case when colors like '%GREEN%' then 1
               when colors like '%RED%' then 1
               when colors like '%PURPLE%' then 1
               ...
               else 0
               end found_colors
from        my_table

but you can see that this is not efficient since I had to manually type each like and the colors.
I tries exist but but it has 0 as output for "RED and GREEN".
I believe there is a better way to do it.
Any suggestions?
BTW I am using pl/sql
Regards,
Nick

maybe I'm misunderstanding but it looks like you are trying to do a many to many relationship in one table. typically many to many requires 3 tables, the two tables and then a lookup table joining the two, makes this kind of thing much easier.

@Nika I'm not sure if I understand your question correct. Do you want something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/HGcV5T1d

as mentioned in my comment it is not entirely clear what you are doing however I think you might want to set this up as a many to many relationship.
the fiddle can be viewed here.   https://dbfiddle.uk/jEPvtHxe
set up your two tables and a lookup table.
CREATE TABLE Color (
    id NUMBER,
    color VARCHAR2(50)
);


CREATE TABLE  RowTable(
  id Number,
  name VARCHAR2(50)
  );

 CREATE TABLE ColorRowLookup(
   id Number,
   colorId Number,
   RowTableId Number
   );

then your first query where you show colors per row you can use Oracle's ListAgg Function.
SELECT 
    rt.name AS "Row",  rt.id AS "Row ID",
    LISTAGG(clr.color, ' AND ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY clr.color) AS "Color"
FROM 
    RowTable rt
JOIN 
    ColorRowLookup crl ON rt.id = crl.RowTableId
JOIN 
    Color clr ON crl.colorId = clr.id
GROUP BY 
     rt.id, rt.name
ORDER BY 
    rt.id;

and the second query where you count up the number of colors is a simple left join.
SELECT 
    clr.color AS "Color",
    COUNT(crl.colorId) AS "Count"
FROM 
    Color clr
LEFT JOIN 
    ColorRowLookup crl ON clr.id = crl.colorId
GROUP BY 
    clr.color
ORDER BY 
    clr.color;


If I got it right, you have the table with sample data provided that you need to compare to a fixed list of 25 colors. The task is to match (or not) the colors from your table with the fixed list.
If that is so then one option is to format your colors as a list exactly the same way that the fixed list is or could be.
To prepare the data create a CTE (grid) and make both lists comma (or some other character) delimited with the delimiter before and after each list.
First some sample data (added one more row with 4 colors):
WITH    -- S a mp l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, COLORS) AS
        ( Select    1, 'RED'                From Dual Union All
          Select    2, 'RED and GREEN'      From Dual Union All
          Select    3, 'RED and ORANGE'     From Dual Union All
          Select    4, 'ORANGE'             From Dual Union All
          Select    5, 'GREEN AND MAGENTA'  From Dual Union All
          Select    6, 'ORANGE AND BLACK'   From Dual Union All 
          Select    7, 'ORANGE AND BLACK and BrOWN AND DARKGREEN'   From Dual
    ),
  color_list (LIST_OF_COLORS) AS    -- fixed list of colors
    ( 
      Select 'WHITE, Black, BRoWN, RED, GREEN, BLUE, CYAN, MAGENTA, GREY, Orange, PINK' From Dual 
    ), 

CTE grid - prepare data for matchings - make both lists uppercase and comma delimited with comma before and after the lists:
  grid AS
    ( Select      t.ID,
                  ',' || Replace(Upper(t.COLORS), ' AND ', ',') || ',' "COLORS",
                  Max(Length( ',' || Replace(Upper(t.COLORS), ' AND ', ',') || ',' ) -
                  Length( Replace( ',' || Replace(Upper(t.COLORS), ' AND ', ',') || ',', ',','' ) ) - 1) Over() "MAX_COLORS_COUNT",
                  ',' || Replace(Upper(cl.LIST_OF_COLORS), ', ', ',') || ',' "LIST_OF_COLORS"
      From        tbl t
      Inner Join  color_list cl ON( 1 = 1)
    )  

/*    R e s u l t :    ( g r i d )
        ID COLORS                                     MAX_COLORS_COUNT LIST_OF_COLORS                                                  
---------- ------------------------------------------ ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 ,RED,                                                     4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,
         2 ,RED,GREEN,                                               4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,
         3 ,RED,ORANGE,                                              4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,
         4 ,ORANGE,                                                  4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,
         5 ,GREEN,MAGENTA,                                           4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,
         6 ,ORANGE,BLACK,                                            4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,
         7 ,ORANGE,BLACK,BROWN,DARKGREEN,                            4 ,WHITE,BLACK,BROWN,RED,GREEN,BLUE,CYAN,MAGENTA,GREY,ORANGE,PINK,   */

Use LEVEL Connect By to iterate particular colors (inner query) and show the matching results using Case expressions in outer query. Group By to eliminate duplicate rows...
--    M a i n    S Q L :   
SELECT    ID, COLORS, COLOR,  
          Case When InStr(LIST_OF_COLORS, ',' || COLOR || ',') > 0 Then 1
          Else 0
          End "COLOR_FOUND", 
          Case When InStr(LIST_OF_COLORS, ',' || COLOR || ',') > 0 Then 'Color Found (' || COLOR || ')'
          Else 'NOT FOUND   (' || COLOR || ')'
          End "NOTES"
FROM ( Select    ID, COLORS, 
                 SubStr(COLORS, InStr(COLORS, ',', 1, LEVEL) + 1, InStr(COLORS, ',', 1, LEVEL + 1) -InStr(COLORS, ',', 1, LEVEL) - 1 ) "COLOR",
                 LIST_OF_COLORS
       From      grid
       Connect By  LEVEL <= MAX_COLORS_COUNT
       Order By    ID, LEVEL
    ) 
WHERE COLOR Is Not Null
GROUP BY ID, COLORS, COLOR, LIST_OF_COLORS
ORDER BY ID

/*    R e s u l t :   
ID  COLORS                           COLOR             COLOR_FOUND  NOTES
--  -------------------------------  ----------------  -----------  ------------------------
 1  ,RED,                            RED                         1  Color Found (RED)
 2  ,RED,GREEN,                      GREEN                       1  Color Found (GREEN)
 2  ,RED,GREEN,                      RED                         1  Color Found (RED)
 3  ,RED,ORANGE,                     ORANGE                      1  Color Found (ORANGE)
 3  ,RED,ORANGE,                     RED                         1  Color Found (RED)
 4  ,ORANGE,                         ORANGE                      1  Color Found (ORANGE)
 5  ,GREEN,MAGENTA,                  GREEN                       1  Color Found (GREEN)
 5  ,GREEN,MAGENTA,                  MAGENTA                     1  Color Found (MAGENTA)
 6  ,ORANGE,BLACK,                   BLACK                       1  Color Found (BLACK)
 6  ,ORANGE,BLACK,                   ORANGE                      1  Color Found (ORANGE)
 7  ,ORANGE,BLACK,BROWN,DARKGREEN,   BLACK                       1  Color Found (BLACK)
 7  ,ORANGE,BLACK,BROWN,DARKGREEN,   BROWN                       1  Color Found (BROWN)
 7  ,ORANGE,BLACK,BROWN,DARKGREEN,   DARKGREEN                   0  NOT FOUND   (DARKGREEN)
 7  ,ORANGE,BLACK,BROWN,DARKGREEN,   ORANGE                      1  Color Found (ORANGE)      */

... the above resultset could be further processed to get you different informations such as number of distinct colors found in fixed list of 25 or a list of distinct colors found/not found or ... ...
Something like (if the above Main SQL is declared as cte grid_2):
--    S Q L :
Select  DISTINCT ID, COLORS, 
        Sum(COLOR_FOUND) Over(Partition By ID) "COUNT_COLOR_FOUND",
        LISTAGG(Case When COLOR_FOUND = 1 Then COLOR End, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By COLOR) Over(Partition By ID) "COLORS_FOUND_LIST",
        LISTAGG(Case When COLOR_FOUND = 0 Then COLOR End, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By COLOR) Over(Partition By ID) "COLORS_NOTFOUND_LIST"
From    grid_2

/*      R e s u l t :
ID  COLORS                            COUNT_COLORS_FOUND  COLORS_FOUND_LIST          COLORS_NOTFOUND_LIST
--  --------------------------------  ------------------  -------------------------  --------------------
 1  ,RED,                                              1  RED    
 2  ,RED,GREEN,                                        2  GREEN,RED 
 6  ,ORANGE,BLACK,                                     2  BLACK,ORANGE  
 5  ,GREEN,MAGENTA,                                    2  GREEN,MAGENTA 
 3  ,RED,ORANGE,                                       2  ORANGE,RED    
 4  ,ORANGE,                                           1  ORANGE    
 7  ,ORANGE,BLACK,BROWN,DARKGREEN,                     3  BLACK,BROWN,ORANGE           DARKGREEN            */

